# How to output results to an S3 bucket when invoking SageMaker endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker

I have managed to create a SageMaker endpoint by using `client.create_endpoint()`, doc is [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint)

By using the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html) to invoke the endpoint, I tested the model runs successfully and gave me the expected result, but I can only print out the result locally, how can I setup the output S3 bucket, and get the prediction result in that bucket when invoking the endpoint?

I wanted to be able to get an output file with the 'json.gz.output' format, the content is something like:

```
{"SageMakerOutput":[[0.05555]],"id":123}
```

I only know if I use 'batch transform jobs', I can setup the output bucket in the code, and the result will be uploaded to the s3 output bucket, but I don't know how to achieve this when using an endpoint, I'm new to SageMaker, can someone help please?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do it in my knowledge (I could be wrong). Why don't you just put the result in your desired form and upload to S3 with the boto client? Look [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) for an example.

Comment: Hi thanks, that's what I'm thinking too, but for 'batch transform jobs' on sagemaker, it can define an output bucket, and when the job is done, the output will be uploaded to that bucket automatically, so does it mean I should use 'batch job' instead of 'endpoint' to make this process simpler?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve.. If you need a persistent endpoint where to send data occasionally and run the inference, you have to go for an endopoint and implement your own S3 upload policy (it's nothing complex, few lines of code..look at the example), instead if you already have a batch of data available for inference, then you can choose the batch transform, look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html